# mbed compiler: how to programatically read & write flash STM32F091RC on Nucleo eval board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash-memory, mbed, stm32f0

I need to write and read back configuration parameters to the STM32F091RC flash.

What are the read and write functions/methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.
[Here is a discussion how.  Click "Import program" next to 00_eeprom_emulation_f091.](https://developer.mbed.org/questions/69101/Is-there-a-way-to-store-variables-in-a-n/)